# how to find the class labels after the one hot encoding in LabelBinarizer sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, data-mining, one-hot-encoding

I am working on cifar data set for classification of images. where i used one hot encoding the class labels as follows:

```
lists = ['frog',
 'truck',
 'deer',
 'automobile',
 'bird',
 'horse',
 'ship',
 'cat',
 'dog',
 'airplane']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer 
label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
label_binarizer.fit(lists)

def one_hot_encode(x):
     return label_binarizer.transform(x)

//here y_train is list of training labels
y_train = one_hot_encode(y_train)

print(y_train[0])
// output as [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

which means ship from the list or its something else? If any thing else can anyone help me to get the class.

As far as i know my first element in the list of train label is frog not a ship thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LabelBinarizer has a inverse_transform function which can be used to get the original value back from the one-hot encoded value.
Check the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.inverse_transform)

And by the way, the values will be stored in alphabetic order in the LabelBinarizer.

Example:

```
label_binarizer.inverse_transform([y_train[0]])
Output:  'frog'
```

Answer (score 0):

they may not be ordered as you wish. You can build a mapping table(dict) for further use like:

```
dict={}
for i in range(len(lists)):
    dict[lists[i]]=y_train[i]

print("your mapping table:\n",dict)
print("\any value is then  accessable by value:\n",'ship',dict['ship'])
```